# Inserting Day of week and Time in Oracle date column

Tags: sql, oracle

Considering the following SQL instruction what should I change in order to insert only the day of the week and the time like Hour and Minutes:

```
INSERT INTO SALA_MATERIA(SALA_ID, MATERIA_ID,HORARIO) VALUES (1,'PT', TO_DATE('FRIDAY 15:00','DAY HH24:MI'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DATE` always has year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds. Trying to create a date from just a day of the week and a time does not make sense.

If you want to store just that information then use a `VARCHAR2` column and not a `DATE`.

If you want to store it as a `DATE` then you will need to specify which Friday and specify a year, month and day as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're actually better off storing an entire date - year, month, day, and time - then you can simply use `TO_CHAR()` or `EXTRACT()` to get the parts of the date you need. To store a Friday in a `DATE` column you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO sala_materia
  ( sala_id, materia_id, horario )
VALUES
 ( 1, 'PT', NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'FRIDAY') );
```

This will get the current time of day as well; to use an arbitrary time you could truncate the results of the `NEXT_DAY` function and then use intervals or standard Oracle date arithmetic:

```
INSERT INTO sala_materia
  ( sala_id, materia_id, horario )
VALUES
 ( 1, 'PT', TRUNC( NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'FRIDAY') ) + INTERVAL '15' HOUR );
```

or

```
INSERT INTO sala_materia
  ( sala_id, materia_id, horario )
VALUES
 ( 1, 'PT', TRUNC( NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'FRIDAY') ) + 15/24 );
```

Intervals might work a bit better if you need to be more granular (i.e., minutes and seconds).

The reason I recommend this course of action instead of merely storing the day of the week and the time in a `VARCHAR2` column is that you can then use `TO_CHAR()` or `EXTRACT()` when displaying the date, using date parts in comparisons, etc. - you could even create function-based indexes or virtual columns based on the results of these functions applied to the `horario` column:

```
CREATE INDEX mydayofweek ON sala_materia ( TO_CHAR(horario, 'DAY') );
```